# Can I find out why this question was deleted?

Tags: support

Can I find out why this question was deleted and whether there are changes that could allow it to be undeleted? I have found an answer and would like to post that.

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302471/why-does-access-recalculate-a-stored-query-when-i-copy-it-can-i-tell-it-not-to

Answer (score 2):

The question was automatically deleted by the system because it seemed 'abandoned'.

This is explained in the Help Centre entry, "[The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions)":

> **If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, **or** a score of 1 and a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - has no active bounty
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
> - isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. (These are termed "abandoned"
> questions in the code.)

The idea being to clean up questions *no one has shown interest in*.

Since you want to add an answer, that is clearly no longer true. I have undeleted the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can see the question [timeline](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/302471/timeline); as its author, I imagine you should be able to. After you originally had posted it, some site members thought it wasn't a good question and suggested it be closed. It hadn't seen any activity for a year, so it was automatically deleted after that.

If you think it's valuable enough, you can always post another question and answer it, though I think it is not on topic on this site. Perhaps [this site](https://superuser.com/) would be a better fit.